# Can a design framework be created upon another?

Tags: design-frameworks

Is it correct, can, or should I base my design framework on another, eg. material.io?

I've been researching this but I can't seem to find a answer to back one of the opinions. Help needed!

Context: 
I'm creating a new framework from scratch, to represent my company's language and brand. I believe I should make it depend as little as possible from another packages, to make it more stable, easier to upgrade and also have less code. 
However, a colleague believes we shouldn't reinvent the wheel and so we should build our own upon, for example, vuematerial.io.
More context: founders and engineering manager already agreed they want their own design framework, so resources/time isn't an issue.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, like is actual building materials like a CSS framework? Or are you talking about the documentation type interaction pattern library? Material design is like specifications + strategy + examples + anti-examples. Bootstrap is just boilerplate common UI pieces to fast-track development. Surely you’re not talking about stick-building your own version of Bootstrap or Foundation CSS just because you have the time/resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most design/development frameworks will fall into one of two categories:

- those that are strongly linked or have a specific design focus versus
- those that are very flexible and modular so that you can take specific parts that you want to implement.

So you may find that with something like bootstrap you can simply take their grid system and if it is compatible with another design/development framework you are using then you can simply choose to use the user interface elements from a different framework without much impact. I think [Atomic Design](http://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/table-of-contents/) was one of those very modular systems that required a little bit of interpretation and adaptation because it is so flexible, and in the end [Pattern Lab](http://patternlab.io/) was created to make the implementation much easier. The same goes for design systems like [IBM's Design Language](https://www.ibm.com/design/language/) that is more fluid and modular while their [Carbon Design System](http://carbondesignsystem.com/) is more specific.

However, when it comes to something like the Fluent Design system by Microsoft, I think you'll have more trouble trying to decouple the various components of the design system because it has a philosophy of supporting the types of devices and interactions that people associate with Microsoft products and applications (same with Apple).

There's nothing to say that you can't start with a design language/system that is close to what you want to create, add a few more components to it, and then build a development system on top of that (and call it the same thing if you want) to come up with something that is tailored to your company/brand/application.

You might find that it is necessarily to refine or create smaller sub design systems if there are many brands or applications that have different purposes as well. The [Westpac GEL](https://gel.westpacgroup.com.au/) is a very good example of this because the company absorbed other finance institutions and needed to unite the overall look & feel digitally but still maintain the individual branding.

[Atlassian Design](https://atlassian.design/) is another example of a design system created for the entire company/brand while allowing for products under the brand to have their own identities. In this case the original product brand guidelines was consolidated into a product brand design guide rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using an already created design framework is a bad idea. My company uses Bootstrap and we created our own design style on top of Bootstrap. For us it made the most sense because you get all the benefits of Bootstrap + our own custom style. It can be a little frustrating forcing the framework to use your custom styles vs Bootstrap's but if you see past that there really isn't an issue in my opinion.